# Tech expert says you are much safer using Windows than Fedora.

Tags: linux, selinux

A tech expert at Michigan State University said today in his talk on campus that with Windows at least you can install ZoneAlarm. Fedora on the other hand has a firewall that is too complex to figure out unless you are an expert at what he called IPTABLES. So most users leave their Fedora firewall unconfigured. Fedora's default is to allow every incoming from anyone and anywhere, so users are unprotected. He said the average user is more protected with Windows than Fedora because of this.

This talk alarmed me as a Fedora user. I tried GUI's like GUFW and Firestarter, neither of which work with Fedora 21.

Can somebody suggest an alternate distro that does have a built-in Firewall - not one like Fedora - but one that actually protects the user?

Comment: "Tech expert"... <sighs>

Answer (score 2):

If you are not familiar in configuring the IPtables in Fedora, you can use the GUI in run level 5 of your Fedora machine.

Commands to install and use the GUI of the Firewall:

To install GUI for Firewall (requires root or sudo previllege):

```
# yum install system-config-firewall
```

To run the GUI, you can either use the command below:

```
#system-config-firewall
```

Or refer to this:

[image: Start GUI Firewall]

You may also wish to visit [Fedora Project website](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_edit_iptables_rules) for more information

[image: Enable Firewall GUI]

**Alternatively you can enable the firewall from your network's router/gateway for mitigation.**